# error install java 16 ubuntu

Tags: java, jar

hi i am trying to install java 16 on ubuntu 18 with the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java16-installer
```

and receive the next error

```
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java16-installer
```

I tried it on different servers and I get the same error.

Comment: Check the packages the ppa provides for your ubuntu version: https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java?field.series_filter=bionic

Comment: Ubuntu Core 18 can't use PPA's, only 18.04 systems can.  (*18 & 18.04 are different Ubuntu products*)

Comment: I have ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please correct your question then, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is not the same product as Ubuntu Core 18.